# Inequality about Schur

Tags: inequality, summation, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, geometric-inequalities

Let a,b,c be the sides of triangle such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $$5(ab+bc+ca)\geq18abc+a+b+c$$
I tried to prove:
$$5(ab+bc+ca)\geq18abc+a+b+c$$$$10(ab+ac+bc)\geq36abc+2(a+b+c)$$$$a(5b+5c-2-12bc)+b(5c+5a-2-12ca)+c(5a+5b-2-12ab)\geq0.$$I tried to prove
$$5b+5c-2-12bc\geq0.$$I know $$-bc\geq-\frac{(b+c)^2}{4}.$$I want to prove $$5(b+c)-2-3(b+c)^2\geq0$$$$5(1-a)-2-3(1-a)^2\geq0$$and I got
$$a(1-3a)\geq0$$which can be wrong.

Comment: Your last inequality holds only when $0\le a\le \frac13$. But as $a$ is arbitrary; that is, it can be replaced by $b$ or $c$, and it is a side of a 'unit' triangle, doesn't this automatically hold? In a triangle, if $a+b+c=1$, then the smallest side has length of at most $\frac13$.

Comment: In your proof, you multiply by 2 and collect terms in a manner that eludes me. My next 2 lines after the statement would be: 

$5ab+5bc+5ac-18abc-a-b-c≥0$
$a(5b+5c-18bc-1)+b(5c-1)-c$

Comment: It seems that you have expressed values of $c$ that have already been expressed in terms of $a$  and  $b$, Likewise, a value of $b$ is already expressed in the parentheses of $a$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I think this question has context (the topic starter thinks that we can use Schur for the proof) and also, he shows attempts. Why did you close this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that:
$$5(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\geq18abc+(a+b+c)^3$$ or
$$10(x+y+z)\sum_{cyc}(x^2+3xy)\geq8(x+y+z)^3+18\prod_{cyc}(x+y)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)\geq0,$$ which is indeed Schur.